# NX Server: NX Protocol on port 22

Tags: redhat, nx, nomachine

New server (RHEL 7) in a very restrictive network environment that permits only a handful of ports for everything connected in the LAN.

22 is accessible and I'm wondering if it's possible to have NX Server use 22 for NX protocol (and not SSH). By definition, NX requires a high number port, so I was wondering if there was a way to listen also to 22.

NX protocol seems to work better for us and it would be great if we could keep it.

Is there a way to tunnel NX, which is setup for port e.g. 4000 to listen to 22, which is open for ssh?

Thank you

Comment: Why using NX when there is X2go based on same protocol, but it is free and without restrictions? And yes, it uses port 22 exactly with the help of SSH, by using a port forwarding, and that is very good thing because you'll gain a key-based auth and all that security at no cost.

Comment: I'm a huge X2Go fan and I've been using it for years (>5). We moved to NX since in this deployment (all RHEL in my experience) is more responsive, works better with RStudio, and the probability of losing a session is smaller.

Comment: It boils down to: can we tunnel MachineNX, which is listening to a high port (e.g. 4000) to 22, which is open for ssh?